# Runtime Sync Failure in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

[image]

I am having above problem when I am trying to replace the .war file of a deployed runtime environment on MobileFirst Server 6.3 which is deployed on Windows 2008 R2.
In error log it is saying that "Unable to create directory". I tried to create that "js" dir manually but I'm getting error "destination path too long"

Comment: How are you trying to replace the file? via GUI or CLI? Also check the server.xml file, since at times while replacing/updating extra application snippets are added which cause the problem in runtime environment initialization.

Comment: I am trying to replace file GUI of server configuration tool

Answer (score 1):

For now i fixed the problem by deleting some project name folder in hierarchy. But still not able to get the reason of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the Path, normally it is not recommended to have a Space in the path and second thing is once I have faced issue with Long Path of the Worklight Projects.

I would recommend shortening the Path somehow, because the issue you are facing Failed to Unzip , which can happen in case of No Permissions or in your case path too long!